# Swing drag/drop: accepting/rejecting file list drop based on # of files / types of files?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I'm using a `DropTarget` and implementing `DropTargetListener` to handle the drop events and it works nicely for accepting Files (just see if the Transferable has a DataFlavor which returns true from `isFlavorJavaFileListType()`).

Now I would like to disallow certain drop types, and give feedback appropriately:

- disallow multiple Files (only a single File accepted)
- disallow a file whose file type is not within an accepted list

Can I do this? I seem to remember working with XPCOM or COM that it was a pain, that in order to get enough information about the drop item, you had to accept it first, so there was this chicken/egg situation where you could only look at the data flavor, and not at the item itself, before accepting a drop.

If I can't reject a dropped set of items ahead of time, is there an appropriate user interface action (make a beep or something) if the dropped data is not valid?

Answer (score 1):

- you can check the list size
- you can use a [mime type library](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html)
  or check file extensions

If you want to play a beep you can do the following :

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```